Blazor upload Ipad
I have a Blazor app with a button that allows users to upload files to Azure storage. It works correctly on both PC and Mac, but it isn't working on the iPad. In Safari on the iPad, the popup to select files opens, but the files are greyed out and disabled. Do you know how to enable Safari to access files on the iPad?
Is there different code that should be used instead of the classic BlazorInputFile for the iPad? Are there any specific permissions that need to be granted to Safari?
Note: I see that it's possible to upload files on sites like ILovePDF from the iPad, so I don't think it's a permission problem on the iPad.
Be able to upload files in Blazor App from an IPad

Welcome to the wonderful world of Apple.  A word of advice-- Blazor is really a complex system of providing and updating markup.  It doesn't have direct control over browser functions like file select or uploading.  So when you have a cross-browser problem, you can usually eliminate Blazor as the culprit.

Thanks for the answer. I finally was able to see the pdf using a standard html input tag instead of BlazorInputFile. It's possible to upload files from safari ipad!

I'm very surprised to hear that, tbh.  But hey, I'm glad it's working for you!

Thanks! just this code 

@GiovanniDeFranceschi It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
